# @font-face sometimes works sometimes and not other times?

Tags: html, css, font-face

I am having an issue with @font-face rule in my css.
In some stylesheets it works perfectly in others it doesn't work at all...

As you can see in the snippet I use an external file for my font but in this particular case it is not working...

Any thoughts anyone?

Endless gratitude will be your share :)

```css
@charset "utf-8"

@font-face {
    font-family: sinhala;
    src: url(fonts/Sinhala.ttc);
}

#wrapperportfolio4 {
 width: 45%;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top: -42.5%;
 box-shadow: 3px 5px 4px 0px black;
 height: 20vw;
 
 
}

#wrapper4trans {
 width: 45%;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top: -42.5%;
 background-color: black;
 opacity: 0.5;
 height: 20vw;
}

#box1title {
 width: 65%;
 font-family: sinhala;
 font-size: 1.0vw;
 color: white;
 margin-top: 2%;
 text-align: center;
}



#box1img {
 width: 60%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin-left: 2.5%;
 margin-top: 1.5%;
 
}

#box1txt{
 width: 25%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 font-family: sinhala;
 font-size: 1.0vw;
 color: white;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top: 5%;
 text-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);

}

#box1txt2{
 width: 25%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 font-family: sinhala;
 font-size: 1.0vw;
 color: white;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top: 5%;
 text-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
}

#box1link {
 width: 25%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 font-family: sinhala;
 font-size: 1.0vw;
 color: white;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top: 5%;
 text-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapperportfolio4">

 <p id="box1title">www.pieterswebdesign.com</p>

 

   <img id="box1img" src="images/box1img.png" />

    <p id="box1txt">Pieter's Web Design is een beginnende webdesigner gevestigd in Gent.</p>

     <p id="box1txt2">Voor betaalbare professionele websites is dit de ideale oplossing.</p>

      <a id="box1link" href="https://www.pieterswebdesign.com">www.pieterswebdesign.com</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are it's the font, as you really need to create a webfont kit and use various font file types:

For example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontName';
    src: url('fontname-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fontname-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('fontname-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), 
         url('fontname-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('fontname-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('fontname-webfont.svg') format('svg');
}
```

You should use a webfont generator like:
https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

(obviously you need to have a licence to use some fonts as webfonts so best to check this before converting any.)

Comment: Thanks, nice of the correct answer to copy mine 10 minutes after I posted mine!

Answer (score 1):

for browsers compatibility you have to use this rule.

```
/* Fonts */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'sinhala';
    src: url("./fonts/sinhala.eot");
    src: url("./fonts/sinhala.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
         url("./fonts/sinhala.woff") format('woff'),
         url("./fonts/sinhala.ttf") format('truetype'),
         url("./fonts/sinhala.svg#montezregular") format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You have to get three formats (woff, eot, ttf) of the FONT.
See the https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator
On this page you can converit the font to correcto format.

Succes!